# Best way of integrating url addresses from database to django url patterns

Tags: python, django

I'm currently playing with django to get acquainted with it. I want to build a litte cms by myself. In an apps model i define a string database-field which represents the url, a field for the bodytext etc. Now i wonder what would be the best way to integrate the url and its corresponding content from the set of data.

Do I have to use views.py for sending database-fields with url data to urls.py?
Is it better to process a database query within urls.py to get the urls?

I hope you can follow me...
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read this question several times and I'm still not sure exactly what you're asking.

The [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial03/#design-your-urls) tells you exactly how to resolve addresses to db entries: capture the components of the URL in your urlconf, pass them to the view, and query your models in the view dependent on the parameters passed from the URL. If this doesn't answer your question, you'll need to explain further what's puzzling you.

Comment: @roseman thanks for you answer. Maybe I don't fully understand the urlconfig und its concept, but i want to have it the other way round. data is being added in the backend and a new url string is added into the database. the frontend doesn't know what urls should being dealt with. Thats why i try to add urls from the data i get in the views.py by querying the database. After i have that information, i would like to configure the urls.py properly...I hope that is more precise...

Comment: I don't understand why this is "the other way round". It's the same: you pass the parameter - eg the path, or the slug - from the URL to the view, and look up the relevant db entry in the view.